# I get this error, how would i fix it?

Tags: grails

```
//if day is sat/sun, set value to W. calendar.set(year,monthNumberForCalendar,dayOfMonth) if(contract.workingDays.id == mondayToFriday.id)
       {                                  
         if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY){ monthMap.put(dayOfMonth, "W")

    URI
        /oulhr/leaveView/show
    Class
        java.lang.NullPointerException
    Message
        Cannot get property 'id' on null object

    //leaveMonths = this.getLeaveMonths(year)    
        def employeeContract = new Contract()
            employeeContract = this.getCurrentContract(employee) leaveMonths = this.getLeaveMonths(year,employeeContract) 

    /*add leave days to month(e.g Jan). When jan is filled up, add to the following month(.e.g Feb)   */       
       int monthNumber = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear.

This is happening because of either `workingDays` or `mondayToFriday` is null.

To confidently say:
 `contract.workingDays.id = mondayToFriday.id`

You have to first make sure that `contract, contract.workingDays, mondayToFriday` are not `null`.